# How to track the previous row before the item in the row equals ceratin value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following dummy data:

```
create table scientist (id integer, firstname varchar(100), lastname varchar(100));
        insert into scientist (id, firstname, lastname) values (1, 'albert', 'einstein');
        insert into scientist (id, firstname, lastname) values (2, 'isaac', 'einstein');
        insert into scientist (id, firstname, lastname) values (3, 'marie', 'einstein');
        insert into scientist (id, firstname, lastname) values (4, 'bob', 'einstein');
insert into scientist (id, firstname, lastname) values (0, 'lola', 'cur');
insert into scientist (id, firstname, lastname) values (4, 'mb', 'cur');
insert into scientist (id, firstname, lastname) values (5, 'peter', 'cur');
        select * from scientist;
```

and I want to get everything before firstname = marie for rows, where lastname = 'einstein' and everuthing that is before firstname mb e.g. where lastname = 'cur'. I assume it can be done by row number, at first count the row number for the row with item which equals to the certain data, after that delete everything where row number is bigger. But the problem is that it will delete everything with the lastname = 'cur' and so on(I have other lastnames).Can it be solved or no?
Desired output are first,second and fifth rows

Comment: show us your desired output

Comment: Your question is somewhat hard to understand. You want to get everything where... and then the problem is it will delete.... So do you want to get data or delete data? If delete, clarify the precise criteria it's not clear what you want to delete or keep.

Comment: @Stu added the desired output

Comment: @eshirvana added

Comment: when there is no order by in you query ,  the order of returned rows by "select * from scientist" is not guaranteed. so when you say rows before a specific row , you need to specify how you sort your data

Comment: @eshirvana I sort my data by lastname and Id

Comment: Are you looking for a SELECT or for a DELETE query?

Comment: @clamp select  query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way :

```
select * from (
select *
, count(case when lastname ='cur' and firstname = 'mb' then 1 
        when lastname ='einstein' and firstname = 'marie' then 1 end) over (partition by lastname order by id) cnt
from scientist s 
) t
where cnt = 0
```